# Bokeh- datetime x_range: 'ValueError, Unrecognized range input'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, bokeh

I have a dataframe `df2` that looks like:

```
DATE       | STATUS
2018-02-01     A
2018-02-02     A
2018-02-02     B
..
2018-02-05     B
```

All the values are string type. I cannot seem to get the dates recognized as dates and plotted onto the x-axis of a stacked bar chart. Here is the most recent of my futile attempts:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool,DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.plotting import figure

#prepare x axis
df2['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE'])
Months=df2["DATE"].tolist()
Months=list(set(Months))  #remove duplicates

IBs=df2["STATUS"].tolist()
IBs=list(set(IBs))

#pivot dataframe
#df2["DATE"]=df2["DATE"].str.strip() #trim values in column
df2=df2.pivot_table(index=['DATE'],columns=['STATUS'], aggfunc=len)
df2=df2.reset_index()
df2=df2.fillna(0) #replace nans with 0

#add plot
source=ColumnDataSource(data=df2)
p= figure(x_range= df2["DATE"], plot_width=700, plot_height=400, x_axis_type='datetime',
x_axis_label='Month', y_axis_label='count')
p.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%Y/%m/%d")

p.vbar_stack(IBs, x='DATE', width=0.9, source=source, legend=[value(x) for x in IBs])

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

thanks in advance.

edit: the errors are `Urecognized range input: [Timestamp('2018-02-02 00:00:00').., Timestamp('2018-02-03 00:00:00')]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue and just figured out what was the problem (at least in my case).

Basically, whatever object you pass into x_range, it must be iterable, containing string type elements only.

Therefore, convert `df2["DATE"]`'s elements' type to str before you pass into x_range.

```
p = figure(x_range=df2["DATE"], ...)  # df2["DATE"] = list(map(str, df['score']))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this is only because you are using strings as coordinates (which are interpreted as categorical factors). If you convert the string values to actual real datetime objects, you could (if desired) use a datetime axis: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#datetime-axes

Answer (score 0):

partial fix: removing the paramerter `x_range` from `figure()`, but my bars disappeared

i suspect my bars disappeared because of this:
[categorical y-axis and datetime x-axis with Bokeh vbar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711567/categorical-y-axis-and-datetime-x-axis-with-bokeh-vbar-plot)

I suspect